# How to enable two consecutive periods in URL without introducing a security vulnerability

Tags: iis, iis-7.5, asp.net

I have a site running on IIS 7.5 which hosts some user-generated content. Recently, I came across a file with two periods in its filename. Let's call it `foo..bar.jpg`. When I attempt to access it, I get a 400 error which unhelpfully just says `Bad Request` in plaintext.

Searching turned up almost nothing, just [this question](https://forums.iis.net/t/1148162.aspx) from the IIS forums where it's stated that this is intended behaviour meant to prevent accessing files outside the web application via the parent directory, `../`. They provide [instructions](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/332117/enable-parent-paths-is-disabled-by-default-in-iis-6-0) on how to disable this check, which would presuambly open my site up to path traversal attacks.

This check is extremely overzealous and blocks many innocuous filenames which I want to be able to support in my application. I can come up with a few workarounds, like force renaming the files or serving them through an `.ashx` handler, neither of which are very appealing.

Is there any way to support URLs containing double periods via `StaticFileHandler` without introducing a path traversal exploit?